# QGIS atlas composer scale

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I am user QGIS and I use composer and atlas to create my maps exports print.
in the atlas settings I use for scale `20% margin` but now I need to print in specific scale numbers.for example if my atlas feature scale where i use scale `20% margin` is the scale is between 100 and 200 then I need to take scale 200.
if the scale is between 1500-2000 then I need to take 2000 scale.

any idea how to do this ?with some condition ?

summary I want to avoid to print features with scales like this `10006` or `12221` I need to print in scales with specific numbers like `10000` or `15000` or `100` or `200`.

[image: atlas]

Answer (score 5):

Check '**Predefinded scale**' in your image.
This option will automatically choose the best fitting predefined scale to show the whole atlas feature.

You can define these scales under:
**project** > **project propertries** > **general** > check **project scales** > click '**+**' and **enter** a **denominator**.

You can set as many scales as you want. You can also create a XML-file of a set of predefined scales for usage in other projects of yours

Comment: that is a good in the some features i loose the 20%margin i need that in the some features maybe to have 1% or 2% is to small margin

Comment: You could use a hidden coverage layer that's a copy of your feature layer with a buffer to get the desired minimum margin.

Comment: @Iamlukesky || this would probably push your feature into the next scale category. If this equals to a 20% margin depends on the presets.